# Error with the relative layout i.e. @+id/edt_message is not a sibling in the same relative layout

Tags: android, android-layout

```
<RelativeLayout >

    <RelativeLayout -------------------------------------------------
        ---------------------------------------------------------
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ScrollView--------------------------
        -----------------------------------
                    ----------------------------------------
        >

        <RelativeLayout --------------------------->

            <EditText -----------------------------------------/>

            <EditText------------------------------------- />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/ll_buttons"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_below="@+id/edt_message"// Problem here 
        android:orientation="horizontal" android:weightSum="2">

        <Button ------------------------------>
        </Button>

        <Button----------------------------->
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

how to get rid off from that error whenever i am trying to do following steps :
1. Right click on poject .
2. In it Android tools--> export signed application package
   This shows an error AS i mention it above 
   because of this error i am unable to create my projects .apk file

Comment: The answer is `-------------------------------------`

Comment: Please post the properly formatted and correct code with the exception.

Comment: oh plz if u r not interested to help so dont post such a silly answer

Comment: Its says that you dont have any relative layout on this layout.xml android:layout_below="@+id/edt_message"

Comment: You dint close your First RelativeLayout closing Tag

Comment: So Show me your full xml

Comment: i was unable to post the full xml code

Comment: rajan it is already closed in my wlayout file the main issue is @+id/edt_msg is not an sibling in same relative layout

Comment: What's the all thing about the -------------------? Remove that. Also, you CAN'T have layout_below if you're not inside a RelativeLayout and not have any edt_message id. If so... please, post your full code.

Comment: Animesh jena i didnt got u please give a appropriate description where i have to do changes to resolve this error

Comment: android:layout_below="@+id/edt_message" is must be in same layout if it is not then u get this error.....

Comment: it is same linear layout and its showing error for the relative layout i just tried to specify use layout_alignbottom bt it didnt worked

Answer (score 1):

You should try this code:

```
<!-- As a parent of your layout -->
<RelativeLayout>

   <ScrollView>

      <RelativeLayout>

         <EditText/>

         <EditText/>

         <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/ll_buttons"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                 android:layout_below="@+id/edt_message" 
                 android:orientation="horizontal"
                 android:weightSum="2">

                  <Button >
                  </Button>

                  <Button>
                  </Button>
          </LinearLayout>

      </RelativeLayout>

   </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

You need to understand that only siblings of the same RelativeLayout can be above, below, right and left of other siblings.
The RelativeLayout is a little bit tricky, if you have a lot of elements inside, you MUST specify the position of all elements, using other siblings ids to adjust as you want.

//EDITED

Use this code to achieve what you want.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:background="@color/zxing_custom_possible_result_points">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/zxing_custom_possible_result_points">


    <ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/ll_buttons"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset"
        android:padding="5dip">

        <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText android:id="@+id/edt_subject"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Subject"
                android:singleLine="true" />

            <EditText android:id="@+id/edt_message"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/edt_subject"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:hint="Add more Requirements"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:minLines="3" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/ll_buttons"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <Button android:id="@+id/btn_send"
            android:layout_width="148dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.49"
            android:text="Send" >
        </Button>

        <Button android:id="@+id/btn_cancel"
            android:layout_width="144dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.44"
            android:text="Cancel">
        </Button>

    </LinearLayout>

  </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: how can i specify  the position since i m new to the android i dont know.

Comment: i just used layout_alignBottom bt it didnt worked for it

Comment: Please specify which layouts would you like in each position.
First the edittext, then another edittext and then the linearlayout, is that correct?

Comment: <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:layout_gravity="center" android:background="#ededed">
 
 <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:id="@+id/header" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="@drawable/customizebid_header">
 </RelativeLayout>

Comment: <ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_below="@+id/header" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:layout_above="@+id/ll_buttons" android:fillViewport="true"
  android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset" android:padding="5dip">

  <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">

Comment: <EditText android:id="@+id/edt_subject"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Subject" android:singleLine="true" />
   <EditText android:id="@+id/edt_message"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/edt_subject" android:gravity="top"
    android:hint="Add more Requirements" android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    
    android:minLines="3" />

Comment: </RelativeLayout>
 </ScrollView>
 

 <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/ll_buttons"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
  android:layout_below="@id/edt_message"
  android:orientation="horizontal" 
  android:weightSum="2">

Comment: <Button
      android:id="@+id/btn_send"
      android:layout_width="148dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="0.49"
      android:text="Send" >

  </Button

Comment: <Button
      android:id="@+id/btn_cancel"
      android:layout_width="144dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="0.44"
      android:text="Cancel" >

  </Button>
 </LinearLayout>
 

</RelativeLayout>

Comment: this is what my code in sequence i was unable to edit the questions so i added it like this sorry for inconvienience plzzzzzz req u to help me

Comment: I will edit my answer. Please check there. 
You have a lot of major problems:
-> the first property in the first RelativeLayout must be an url. You should use as this: xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

-> you don't understand very well what's an scrollview. You're trying to use it as a RelativeLayout, setting some properties that does not belong to it.

-> you don't understand very well what's an RelativeLayout. You can only use the properties to it's siblings if you specify it inside this RelativeLayout, not outside.

Comment: I edited my answer again. Somehow the last </RelativeLayout> wasn't showing. Please check there agian.

Comment: Nice! If it's correct, please accept as answer to your problem. =)

Comment: android:layout_below="@+id/edt_message"  u skipped this line in linear layout i was facing problem here

Comment: Don't think you need it, according to my edited answer. If you use this, you'll face the same problem, since the linearlayout is not sibling of the relativelayout that contains the buttons. If my answer is correct, accept it.

Comment: I don't think you've accepted it, you just voted it up. That's why I asked if it was correct.

Answer (score 0):

I guess edt_message is not inside the LinearLayout.You can not position something that is out side the LinearLayout with respect to something that is inside the LinearLayout.I hope this might help you

Comment: Just put your edt_message inside ll_buttons LinearLayout and try once.

Comment: it is inside the linear layout

Comment: can you please post your complete xml file instead of -------- m,arks

Comment: i tried to post the full code bt it was showing an error

Comment: just copy and paste your code,,press ctrl+A,then press ctrl+L,then try to post

Comment: m not able to do that now plz will scroll down there i had pasted my code in a sequence in a comment

Comment: @Gurleen:-put this line inside the Relative layout that is inside the scrollView.:- android:id="@+id/rlvalue".Now inside the LinearLayout ,where you are getting the error in place of  "android:layout_below="@+id/edt_message"",put    android:layout_below="@+id/rlValue"  .Hope it might help